# Empty cells showing as non-empty when trying to fill in

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with 3 columns, the first 2 were concatenated into the 3rd one.

Then I ran this VBA in order to make the empty cells equal to the above populated cell.

```
Sub fillempty()


With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
.Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Saying that there are no empty cells, despite being visible empty. So if I take the so called non-empty cells but visible empty and clear content and run the VBA again, it does populate.

The problem arises because I have hundreds of thousands of values.

If I run the VBA independently for 1st or 2nd column works, but not for the Concatenated one.
It appears that some cells are empty with the naked eye, but unless their content is cleared the script won't work...

`C2 = IF(A2 <> "", CONCATENATE(A2, B2), "")` then dragged it down for hundreds of thousands of values

Any help would be more than appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Cells with formulas are not "Blank" as far as SpecialCells is concerned.

Comment: Right, I understand. So is there a way to skip the formula of concatenation on blank cells? Even if I copy just the values of the 3rd column C (concatenated one) into a 4th column D, it still won't work..

Comment: `=IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=0,"Blank","Not Blank")`

Comment: Concatenation of `" "` and `" "` will appear blank in the cell but in reality there are 2 spaces `"  "`. What the above formula will do is TRIM it and then check the length using LEN

Comment: Thank you both! Appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to preserve the concatenate formula in the non-blank cells?

Comment: @TimWilliams no, no need to preserve concatenate formula in non-blank cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c in Selection.Cells
    if Len(Trim(c.value))=0 Then c.value=c.offset(-1,0).value
Next c
```

or faster as long as you don't need to preserve any formulas:

```vb
Dim r as long, c as long, data, cols as long
data = selection.value
cols = ubound(data, 2)
for r=2 to ubound(data, 1)
    for c = 1 to cols
        if Len(Trim(data(r, c))) = 0 Then data(r, c) = data(r-1, c)
    next c
next r

selection.Value = data
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout - added

Answer (score 1):

The `isEmpty()` function is handy, too. It returns `FALSE` if there's a formula in it (but the cell is clear). Looks like this:

```
Sub IsA1ReallyEmpty()
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Yep, A1 is empty."
    Else
        MsgBox "Nope, it has stuff in it."
    End If
End Sub
```